# Embedding python and numpy in a portable C++ application with CMake

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I am currently writting a C++ application. I want to use a library that is exclusively written in Python and that uses numpy. I know that there is an [extensive documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) on how to embed Python in a C++ program. My problem comes from the fact that with this method, there needs to be a Python installation on the machine where the app will be installed. However, I want to be able to distribute the program on machine where the user does not have all the rights.

If I am not mistaken, Blender is doing something very similar to what I want to achieve. Basically, when you download a portable version of Blender, you will find a structure like this:

```
blender/
     2.90/
        datafiles/
        python/
            bin/ <-- Contains the Python executable and Python DLL
            DLLs/ <-- Contains the base packages and DLLs of a standard Python installation
                      (such as libssl, asyncio, ...)
            lib/
                [...] <-- Different python packages
                site-packages/ <-- Additional packages such as numpy
        scripts/ <-- Contains the python scripts relative to Blender
```

Basically, Blender ships with its own Python installation with the correct packages. I tried to look at the [Blender source code](https://github.com/blender/blender) to understand how they did it, but I was quickly overwhelmed by the complexity of the code. Still, I managed to find some clues in the `blender/source/creator` [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/creator/CMakeLists.txt).

I am using CMake (3.10) for my build system and using MinGW for the compilation. I plan to support Linux sometime in the future, but I first want to concentrate on Windows. Here is a little overview on my what my objectives are:

1. I want that CMake automatically creates a structure like the one shown above, with the desired packages. For me it is ok if this kind of structure is created in the `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`. Bonus point if it is possible to automatically download locally Python and install the packages (to avoid messing with the default Python installation on the system of the developper).
2. I need to tell my C++ application to use the correct Python environment (the one that will be created in 1.)

P.S.

I am also considering using [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11), which has a [embedding part](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html). But the problems are more or less the same as above.